# <rich:listShuttle> -- Preventing duplicates?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam

I have a data model in which I have an `Item` that can belong to one or more `Categories`.  I'm trying to display a `<rich:listShuttle />` allowing the user to select which `Categories` the `Item` should belong to.  I'm using RichFaces and Seam 2.2.x, and haven't run into any problems in setting the values initially.  My source is a list of the defined `Categories`, while my target is the `Item.values()` attribute.  Everything works fine when setting the `Categories` for the first time.

However, when I go in to edit an `Item` and change the `Categories` it is in, my `<rich:listShuttle />` source list contains all of the `Categories`, not just the one the `Item` is not currently in.  As a result, it is possible to move a duplicate `Category` from the source over to the target.  This creates problems when I try and commit my `Item` to the database.

Is there any way to prevent these duplicates from being set?  I would think there was a flag I could set, but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: show some code.. it is way easier to get to know the issue from code, rather than explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully fix this issue by changing from `<rich:listShuttle />` to `<rich:pickList />`.  It accomplished everything I was looking for, and dealt well with the duplicates issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code or truly understanding your problem, you can remove duplicates by using a Set instead of a List.

If your `Categories` has implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` you can easily remove duplicates by putting everything in a `Set` before adding it to the list.

```
Set<Categories> uniqueSet = new HashSet<Categories>(categoriesCollection);
List<Categories> backToList = new ArrayList<Categories>(uniqueSet);
```

Comment: The `rich:listShuttle` control `targetValue` must be of type `java.util.List` -- it cannot be an instance of `Set`.

Comment: Yes, and if you look at my code you see that I put the set inside a List